# removing effect of ng-deep on component destroy

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4, vmware-clarity

I hate to use ng-deep but there is no better alternative for this.

I am using VMware Clarity https://v1.clarity.design/modals in my project and for some cases, I need to overwrite modal-body class. So, I am overwriting it using this in my component.scss file:

```
::ng-deep .modal-body {
  overflow-y: visible;
  overflow-x: visible;
}
```

This serves my purpose. But the problem starts for other modals. After opening above modal, if I open any other modal, above styling affects those too. I want above styling only for one modal. So how I can do that.

I was wondering if there is an option to reset above style when the component gets destroyed or What Angular Suggests.

Comment: Any way to distinctly access just the VMware modal which you need to change? if not, add a `customClass` to all your modals and then use CSS's `:not` selector

Comment: adding a custom class doesn't work. I am using component for modal

Comment: @vmware-clarity team any suggestion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just write your selector to be more specific so it targets only the desired modal.

```html
<clr-modal class="overflow-modal">...</clr-modal>
```

```css
::ng-deep .overflow-modal .modal-body {
  overflow-y: visible;
  overflow-x: visible;
}
```